# How can I add .php and .js files in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am new to WordPress and I want ask that how I can add .php files in the WordPress through Visual Editor. I won't be using those files directly but I need to validate some HTML form by calling that php script through Ajax. I am very good at PHP and many other web programming languages but I have never use WordPress. I would be highly grateful if you could help me with that. I can have more than 20 php files so I think it would pretty absurd to add all these files by adding new pages in the WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not have access to the FTP server, you will need a plugin, like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-upload/ to upload the PHP script to wp-contents folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend uploading them to a `/php/` subfolder in your `wp-content/uploads/` folder via FTP. Then on your form you would point to a url like `action=/wp-content/uploads/php/test.php`